# Azure Active Directory login through golang command line application

Tags: azure, go, automation, azure-active-directory, devops

I am building a command line application in golang and I want to authenticate users to the application. That application is integrated with Azure AD and just requires user's email-ID to login (user-interface way) basically I am automating some of the process in that application so I am not aware of the process that should be followed.

I was thinking to get the accessToken using this command

```
az account get-access-token
```

using the access token I will provide that to the apiToken field in the exposed api provided to me but somehow it is not working